# How to override PasswordResetConfirmView? (django.contrib.auth.views)

Tags: django, django-views, django-authentication

I tried:

```
class CustomPasswordResetConfirmView(PasswordResetConfirmView):
    form_class = CustomSetPasswordForm
```

but it raises `TypeError:__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

must use **init** method|| function to pass agrument

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordResetView,PasswordResetConfirmView
class New_PasswordResetConfirmView(PasswordResetConfirmView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(New_PasswordResetConfirmView,self)
```

https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/super/working-python-super-function